# What is an easy way to do a timer?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, timer, timeout

I'm writing a Ruby script and want behaviour like this:

```
every 15 seconds do
  callback
end
```

How would I do this?

A quick search didn't show many libraries; Should I be using threads? I want this pretty basic since my Ruby script is going to be basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always call [`sleep`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sleep):

```ruby
loop do
  sleep 15
  callback
end
```

Comment: Was hoping I wouldn't have to do that, but I guess that seems to be the way to go. So the solution would be to create a separate thread that runs callback and start the thread when I need that task. Cool, thanks!

Comment: What specifically is your use case? If this is a synchronous script that doesn't need to do anything in parallel, calling sleep should be fine. Otherwise, there are other approaches you could try. EventMachine is one (as Ryan mentioned in a different answer); you could also attempt to refactor your script to run within a simple `loop` and manually check `Time.now`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also checkout EventMachine's PeriodicTimer class. I've used this with success in the past: http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/PeriodicTimer.html

EventMachine may be overkill for your needs, though.